# HP Proliant ML350 G6: where is temp sensor #3?

Tags: hp-proliant

I have a ML350 G6 dual processor.

Yesterday it suddenly shut down and logged a critical shutdown because high temperature detected in sensor number 3, but I can't find in HP documentation any info about sensors location.

I have no installed other HP software apart from HP management, a very basic Web interface with only logs. Is there any other software which could give me more information about the error? I have read something about iLo, but I didn't find any download for my server in HP support page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem in this serves was that one of the plastic bracket/fastener of one of the cpu heatskins was broken. Bracket replaced and problem solved.

Anyway, the info abou iLo was really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the ILO interface of the server. It is a separate port on the back of the chassis labeled "ILO2".

You can program it from the BIOS or use the default login/password listed on the server's asset tag.

[image]

Once in the ILO, you can look at the IML log and server status to show the health of the internal components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try and inform